# is it possible to apply code format before git diff command

Tags: git

I was working on a old repo, I have config my editor to auto apply black and isort while save,
but the repo code not. So while I try to diff, there will always be so much diff message to views. So I wonder if it possible to apply black and isort while call git diff, So I can only check the logic different, but not the format.

Comment: Format the code and commit the format changes before making other changes.

Comment: It not my code. As I have said, I was working on a old and big repo. Every time I edit a file, it will diff too much, make it hard to check the diff and do code review in gitlab

Comment: You can commit first and then remove it from the branch (by `git rebase -i`) before pushing the other commits.

Answer (score 1):

There is a diff tool based of syntax that support over 20 programming languages (Python is one of them). This tool is experimental and you can review in Github, [DiffStatic](https://github.com/Wilfred/difftastic).

Comment: The name is "Difftastic"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the options to avoid spaces/eol change. Try `git diff -w` but there are others. Check `git help diff`

Comment: black makes too many non-white-space changes for this to work well. Better to just reformat the code before making any changes, then compare to the reformatted version.

Comment: I have search google, seems I can got what I want by use the low level git command and do some dirty work, but It seems too hard for me.

Answer (score 0):

This feature was rejected from black (see https://github.com/psf/black/issues/245) but on Unix systems you can use the below `black-diff` function to get the basic functionality (allowing to compare a single file against the latest version, or two revisions of a single file):

Check changes since last commit:

```sh
black-diff test.py
```

Compare two versions of a file between branches:

```sh
black-diff main:test.py feature_branch:test.py
```

The function itself (you can add it to your `~/.bashrc` for convenience):

```sh
black-diff () {
  if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "Please provide path to the modified file (or two revisions of a file) to compare"
    return 1
  fi
  if [[ $# -eq 1 ]]; then
    # compare latest revision against current version
    cat $1 | black -q - | diff --color -u <(git show "$(git branch --show-current):$1" | black -q -) -
  else
    # compare two revisions
    git show $1 | black -q - | diff --color -u <(git show $2 | black -q -) -
  fi
}
```